# Get textview of custom adapter android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I have a custom view adapter with four buttons and a title that populate a ListView.

When a user clicks one of those buttons, I want to retrieve the title associated with that specific adapter. 
So far I have tried retrieving the parent and getting the textView but that does not return the correct title. 
So...how would I get the specific title affiliated to the adapter that has the button the user clicked on?

I'd be happy to clarify if you need more information.

Here is the layout of the adapter.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_student_home_classTitle_textView"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_student_home_grades"
                android:background="#ffff130c" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_student_home_grades_imageButton"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_grades_512"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_student_home_notification_textEdit"
                android:background="#ffff130c" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_student_home_notification_imageButton"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_bell_512"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_student_home_homework"
                android:background="#ffff130c" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_student_home_homework_imageButton"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_foundation_book_bookmark_simple_black_512x512"
                android:contentDescription="@string/homework_notification_icon"
                android:background="#00000000" />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_student_home_attendance"
            android:background="#ffff130c" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_student_home_attendance_imageButton"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_attendance"
            android:contentDescription="@string/homework_notification_icon"
            android:background="#00000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the adapter where I implemented the onClick

```
public class ClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SchoolClass> implements View.OnClickListener{
private SchoolClass aClass;
public ClassAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SchoolClass> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

}

public SchoolClass getSchoolClass(){
    return this.aClass;
}

public void setSchoolClass(SchoolClass schoolClass){
    this.aClass = schoolClass;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.classes_adapter, null);
    }

    aClass = getItem(position);


    if(aClass != null){
        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_student_home_classTitle_textView);
        if(title != null){
            title.setText(aClass.getTitle());
        }
        setSchoolClass(aClass);
    }
    //set buttons
    ImageButton notificationsButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_student_home_notification_imageButton);
    ImageButton gradesButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_student_home_grades_imageButton);
    ImageButton attendanceButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_student_home_attendance_imageButton);
    ImageButton homeworkButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_student_home_homework_imageButton);
    notificationsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    gradesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    attendanceButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    homeworkButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ClassActivity.class);
    View parent = (View) v.getRootView();
    //v.getParent() returns null when I look for the textView
    TextView title = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.fragment_student_home_classTitle_textView);
    System.out.println("\n\n title: " + title.getText().toString() + " \n\n");
    intent.putExtra("__CLASS_NAME__", title.getText().toString());
```

It populates a list view and if I were to click on fragment_student_home_attendance_imageButton I would want to get the fragment_student_home_classTitle_textView associated with that ClassAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a idea to you, hope this can help to fix the problem :)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;
  // ....
ImageButton notificationsButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_student_home_notification_imageButton);
notificationsButton.setTag(R.id.fragment_student_home_notification_imageButton);
  // ....
return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v!=null && v.getTag()!=null && v.getTag()==R.id.fragment_student_home_notification_imageButton){

      // do something you like
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I actually already have a switch statement for the four buttons in my adapter. 
I just didn't add that at the end of my code. The main problem right now is with the onClick(View v) function, I am trying to get a view that is part of the adapter but NOT clickable. I have tried 
View parent = v.getParent() but then 
TextView textview = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.fragment_student_home_classTitle_textView) returns null, even though it is listed in my XML file above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind, I got it.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ClassActivity.class);


    //It's the parent of the parent OF THE parent where
    //the textView lies in my layout.
    View parent = (View) v.getParent().getParent().getParent();


    TextView title = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.fragment_student_home_classTitle_textView);
    System.out.println("\n\n title: " + title.getText().toString() + " \n\n");
    intent.putExtra("__CLASS_NAME__", title.getText().toString());
```

If there is a better way to get this solution, as it seems like a head on approach to the problem, I welcome any comments!